# FileSystemWatcher - On Delete, copy a file

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a question, I am creating a FileWatcher to monitor a folder, and I am trying to create a method that copies the deleted file from another location.

It is this possible using the FileSystemEventHandler?

Alternatively, in last case, can I restrict the folder to changes with the FileSystemWatcher?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to implement something similar to [Windows Protected Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/222193/description-of-the-windows-file-protection-feature)? If so, I'm not sure that you can do it without being Windows. If not, I'm not understanding your scenarios clearly.

Comment: I have a folder with 3 files, I want to monitor the folder.
If one of the files is deleted i want that the filewatcher Copys the same file from other folder.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Did you look at [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.deleted.aspx)?

Comment: Are you saying that if a file, that is being monitored, is deleted then you want to restore it from somewhere else? Because if this is the question, did you try using the .Deleted event on the FSW class?

Comment: Yes, I have done all the code from the [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

But I can't pass variables or functions to FileSystemEventArgs. 
CODE:
Monitor.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

Comment: Encapsulate the FSW object inside your own class and pass values to the events using fields.

Comment: but .Deleteed is only fired for deleted items in wherever you told it to monitor.. what exactly isnt working for you

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something along the lines of the following:

```
using System.IO;

//...

const string SourceDirectory = @"\\myServer\share\originalFiles";
private static void OnDeleted (object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{

    //this will help prove if the fsw is being triggered / whether the error's in your copy file piece or due to the trigger not firing
    Debug.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
    Debug.WriteLine(e.ChangeType);

    var filename = e.Name; //NB: Returns path relative to the monitored folder; e.g. if monitoring "c:\demo" and file "c:\demo\something\file.txt" is changed, would return "something\file.txt"
    //var filename = Path.GetFilename(e.FullPath); //if you don't want the above behaviour, given the same scenario this would return "file.txt" instead
    var sourceFilename = Path.Combine(SourceDirectory, filename);

    /* not sure if this is required: see https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/437
    while (File.Exists(e.FullPath)) { //just in case the delete operation is still in progress when this code's triggered.
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    */

    File.Copy(sourceFilename, e.FullPath);
}

//...

const string MonitoredDirectory = @"\\myServer\share\watchedFiles\";
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
    fsw.Path = MonitoredDirectory;
    fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    //fsw.Filter = "*.xml"; //add something like this if you want to filter on certain file extensions / that sort of thing 
    fsw.OnDeleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    Console.WriteLine("This monitor will now run until you press 'x' (i.e. as we need to keep the program running to keep the fsw in operation)");
    while(Console.Read() != 'x');
}
```

(the above is untested)

Comment: Does this work? Isn't the file deleted before this event is raised?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd as mentioned, this isn't tested.  However it shouldn't be an issue; we're not copying the deleted file, but rather picking up the "template" and copying it to the deleted file's former location.  The only potential issue's related to the race condition where the file may not have been completely deleted by the time the copy's invoked; for that you'd need to uncomment the `while (File.Exists(e.FullPath))` loop... but that may lead to an infinite loop were the file recreated between deletion & our code running; so would then need a timeout to improve / protect against such scenarios